# Objective-C class properties order

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

A short question: Does Objective-C has a determined order for properties of classes in a runtime? (I need some link to a documentation with description of this behavior)
A long question: if I have a class:

```
@interface OneUnitClass: NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* p1;
@property (nonatomic) NSRange p2;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSString* p3;
@end
```

Then in the runtime I will have an order of properties:

> OneUnitClass: p1, p2, p3

But if I have a class divided by categories:

```
@interface ClassWithExtensions : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* p1;
@end

@interface ClassWithExtensions ()
@property (nonatomic) NSRange* p2;
@end

@interface ClassWithExtensions ()
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSString* p3;
@end
```

I will have other order:

> ClassWithExtensions: p3, p2, p1

To print an order of properties, I use a code:

```
void printPropertyNamesForClass(Class targetClass) {
    unsigned propertyCount = 0;
    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList(targetClass, &propertyCount);
    if (!properties) {
        return;
    }
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < propertyCount; ++i) {
        objc_property_t markerProperty = properties[i];
        const char* propertyName = property_getName(markerProperty);
        NSLog(@"Property: %@", [NSString stringWithCString:propertyName encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    }

    free(properties);
}
```

Comment: May i ask what you expect from (or to do with) sorted properties list? alignment optimisation like C structs?

Comment: I try to fix @annotate macros in libextobjc: https://github.com/K-Be/libextobjc/blob/master/extobjc/EXTAnnotation.h
This macro allows to add some annotations for properties and classes, but bases on properties order. I do not want to add property name into macro.

Comment: Does it matter? I checked that code, I think it should work as long as you put the annotate just before the property. The order of the properties don't really matter - or so it seems. What happens if you add annotate to your p2 or p3 in ClassWithExtensions e.g?

Comment: Yes, it is matter :(. Because, implementation uses property order, and assume, that in runtime order of properties is not changed. In a constructor on line https://github.com/K-Be/libextobjc/blob/925e1d5eef18ef1407b0affbc64b75edb5682ef4/extobjc/EXTAnnotation.m#L32 , the code tries to find property name by index.